# CruiseControl doesn't run as a Windows service

Tags: windows, java, port, cruisecontrol

I am having a problem with CruiseControl on Windows. I can get CruiseControl to run on its own without problems right after installation.

However, when I run the Windows service for cruise control (needed for the web dashboard),  its seems to me that the CruiseControl and wrapper.exe (the service) cannot seem to share the ports - observed from the following excpetions thrown:

```
ontrollerAgent- Exception starting httpAdaptor
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)

ontrollerAgent- Exception starting connectorServer
java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL [jrmp]: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: jrmp [Root exception is java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException: jrmp]
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.newIOException(Unknown Source)
```

I have asked a similar quesion before on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2332192/cruisecontrol-cannot-get-web-interface-to-work

However, it is only now that I have determined that the conflict is betwen the Windows service (Wrapper.exe) and CruiseControl, which means that the solution to that question doesn't really solve my problem. I still cannot get my web dashboard to display, although the actual CruiseControl application seesm to work fine. I get this error:

```
While trying to retrieve the URL: http://127.0.0.1:8080/cruisecontrol    
The following error was encountered:    
    * Connection to 127.0.0.1 Failed     
The system returned:    
    (111) Connection refused    
The remote host or network may be down. Please try the request again.
```

Any idea how to get CruiseControl to working as a Windows service?

---

Full stack traces

```
[cc]Feb-25 16:33:49 ontrollerAgent- Starting HttpAdaptor with CC-Stylesheets
[cc]Feb-25 16:33:49 ontrollerAgent- starting httpAdaptor
[cc]Feb-25 16:33:49 ontrollerAgent- Exception starting httpAdaptor
java.net.BindException: Address already in use: JVM_Bind
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketBind(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(Unknown Source)
        at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at mx4j.tools.adaptor.PlainAdaptorServerSocketFactory.createServerSocket (PlainAdaptorServerSocketFactory.java:24)
        at mx4j.tools.adaptor.http.HttpAdaptor.createServerSocket(HttpAdaptor.java:672)
        at mx4j.tools.adaptor.http.HttpAdaptor.start(HttpAdaptor.java:478)
        at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.jmx.CruiseControlControllerAgent.start(CruiseControlControllerAgent.java:172)
        [truncated]

[cc]Feb-25 16:33:49 ontrollerAgent- starting rmiRegistry
[cc]Feb-25 16:33:49 ontrollerAgent- Port 1099 is already in use, so no new rmiRe
gistry is started
[cc]Feb-25 16:33:49 ontrollerAgent- starting connectorServer
[cc]Feb-25 16:33:50 ontrollerAgent- Exception starting connectorServer
java.io.IOException: Cannot bind to URL [jrmp]: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: jrmp [Root exception is java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException: jrmp]
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.newIOException(Unknown Source)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(Unknown Source)
        at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.jmx.CruiseControlControllerAgent.start(CruiseControlControllerAgent.java:190)
        at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.Main.startJmxAgent(Main.java:137)
        at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.Main.start(Main.java:115)
        at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:259)
        at net.sourceforge.cruisecontrol.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:117)

Caused by: javax.naming.NameAlreadyBoundException: jrmp [Root exception is java.
rmi.AlreadyBoundException: jrmp]
        at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.bind(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.bind(Unknown Source)
        at javax.naming.InitialContext.bind(Unknown Source)
        at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.bind(Unknown Source)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.rmi.AlreadyBoundException: jrmp
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl.bind(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Skel.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.oldDispatch(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(Unknown Source)
        at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        [truncated]
2010-02-25 16:33:50.710::INFO:  Logging to STDERR via org.mortbay.log.StdErrLog
2010-02-25 16:33:50.850::INFO:  jetty-6.1.11
2010-02-25 16:33:51.161:/dashboard:INFO:  Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
```

Comment: DID YOU MAKE SURE YOU HAVE CAPS LOCK TURNED ON?

Comment: @Urda, huh, what do you mean?

Comment: @bguiz, Sorry I was trying to make a funny :-\ http://twitpic.com/16dlmj